# What does Viktor Navorski say to Milodragovich in Bulgarian?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-terminal

In the movie The Terminal, during the scene where a Russian man is not allowed to take the medicine, assumed to be for his ailing father, without an MPL.

What does Viktor Navorski say to Milodragovich so that he replies.

> *Medicine for goat.*

Is the medicine really for goat or Viktor knew the rule and is trying to help the person?

Comment: I don't know what he said but Viktor did indeed know about the rule, and probably hinted as much to the Russian guy to help him out.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has basically two parts: **What does Viktor Navorski say to Milodragovich** and **Is the medicine really for goat or Viktor knew the rule and is trying to help the person?**

I would try to answer them in that order
From this clip you can find the scene: [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrTUmYxnNlo&t=227s) at around 3:44sec what [Viktor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0362227/characters/nm0000158?ref_=tt_cl_t1) says in English, roughly translates to "***izgo dasnaya zakogo ele karsvoto***" with his pauses but in reality that would be more like

> "izgo dasnaya lekarstvo za koza"

This is from a Bulgarian [website](http://www.guusbosman.nl/node/1087) and its comments. I took the Bulgarian comments and used Google Translate to understand the first part of the sentence.
[I admit Google Translate is not always the most accurate one, but for your first question I needed a somewhat rough idea of what Viktor said, so that Mr. Milodragovich could reply the actual word]

[image]
[image]

I had to use this crude approach as I could not find any authentic mention of this translation on the internet.Even in the script it was written "Hanks speaks in Bulgarian" [Source](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/t/terminal-script-transcript-tom-hanks.html)
So, my answer to your first question would be: **Mr Milodragovich possibly knew at least the meaning of "Koza" in English is "Goat" and rest of the information was supplied by Viktor in this Bulgarian dialogue.**

As for your second ques: **The medicine was actually for the father or else if it had been for the goat, Viktor would have easily interpreted it and all these scenes wouldn't have followed.** Moreover the helpless expression of Mr Milodragovich and falling on his knees do suggest the same.

In this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrTUmYxnNlo&t=227s) [Frank Dixon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0362227/characters/nm0001804?ref_=tt_cl_t3) mentions:

> Dixon: You'av been reading the immigration forms, the blue one.
>
> Viktor: Blue?
>
> Dixon: Yes.The blue form, the one that says if its an
> animal he doesn't need the Medicinal Purchase License

At the end of the scene the expression on Viktor's face(the way he smiles) confirms the sense of happiness and satisfaction of being able to help a person (supposedly from close to his native) in spite of the fact that he didn't know him.

Answer (score -1):

1. Viktor says: **"Искат да знаят за кого е лекарството"**, which translates into **"They want to know who the medicine is for"**.
2. No, the medicine isn't actually for a goat. In *Bulgarian, Russian or Macedonian* the words **goat** and **father** are not even remotely close. The only similarity is in English. The word **god** *as in Lord* is a synonym to the word **father**. That's probably why the animal in the film is specifically a goat and not just a dog for example.

Comment: Hi Aleks, welcome to Movies & TV. Could you please expand on your 2nd paragraph? Some explanation and backup would be more useful for future readers, because as it stands, it just sounds like an opinion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).